# How to set an activity as idempotent in Oracle SOA Suite

Tags: soa, bpel

I read a document from Oracle which explains what is idempotent in BPEL.

> > 13.3.2 Partner Link Property
>
> You can dynamically configure a partner link at runtime in BPEL. This
>   is useful for scenarios in which the target service that BPEL wants to
>   invoke is not known until runtime. The following Partner Link
>   properties can be tuned for performance:
>   13.3.2.1 idempotent
>
> An idempotent activity is an activity that can be retried (for
>   example, an assign activity or an invoke activity). Oracle BPEL Server
>   saves the instance after a nonidempotent activity. This property is
>   applicable to both durable and transient processes.
>
> Values:
>
> This property has the following values:
>
> ```
> False: Activity is dehydrated immediately after execution and recorded in the dehydration store. When idempotent is set to False, it
> ```
>
> provides better failover protection, but may impact performance if the
>   BPEL process accesses the dehydration store frequently.
>
> ```
> True (default): If Oracle BPEL Server fails, it performs the activity again after restarting. This is because the server does not
> ```
>
> dehydrate immediately after the invoke and no record exists that the
>   activity executed. Some examples of where this property can be set to
>   True are: read-only services (for example, CreditRatingService) or
>   local EJB/WSIF invocations that share the instance's transaction.

But I wonder is there anyway to set an activity as non-idempotent or idempotent in design time and runtime?

Answer (score 1):

idempotent property can be set at partnerLink operation level using DeploymentDescriptor property idempotent.
Refer to Section c.1 Introduction to Deployment Descriptor properties of soa dev doc